# Same Code is not working on Cluster setup on remote machine

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I have written code for model training using  pyspark it is working fine for standalone mode or local machine but when i tried to run same code on cluster setup on remote machine it is giving following error.

```
data_train = spark.read.csv(path=path, header=True, quote='"', sep=",")
AttributeError: 'DataFrameReader' object has no attribute 'csv'.
```

Comment: What version of spark are you using? Could it be that the versions of spark are different (i.e. you are using 2.X.X and the cluster 1.6.X)? If using spark 1.6.X could it be that the configuration is different (i.e. csv package was added locally but not on the remote cluster)?

Comment: Which version of spark are you using in cluster?

Comment: There is no change in version and csv is added on remote also.

Comment: i am using spark of version 2.0.0